# select a single field with applying filters in elasticsearch

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I would like to select all the filename field values by ACCOUNT and APPLICATION_NAME
Assuming as in SQL I need to do this :

```sql
select filename.keyword from XXX where ACCOUNT='monitoring' and APPLICATION_NAME='webapp'
```

this is a screenshot of a log entry sample in the kibana interface

[image]

Comment: Did you try using the Kibana Query Language (KQL). Use the following ACCOUNT:'Monitoring' and APPLICATION_NAME:'webapp' in the search that might sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

selecting the unique values of a specific field is exactly like running an aggregation query at one of the SQL databases
for example

- selecting by field.keyword is something like passing an enum value that should exactly match one of the existing values against this field.
- setting size to 0 will retrieve the aggregation result only without associating with it the list of sources.
- in an agg query as I said above it is selecting one of the aggregation functions against some fields that could be one or more
- incase they are multiple this should become a composite aggregation.
- Composite aggregartion require specifing composite.sources in the query request body.

this query worked for me in case I wanted to selelct filename and POD_ID uniques pairs.

```
{
          "size": "0",
          "aggs": {
            "custom_agg_name_whatever_you_want": {
              "composite": {
                "sources": [
                  {
                    "FILENAME": {
                      "terms": {
                        "field": "filename.keyword"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "POD_ID":{
                      "terms": {
                        "field": "POD_ID.keyword"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "filter": [
                {
                  "bool": {
                    "filter": [
                      {
                        "bool": {
                          "should": [
                            {
                              "match_phrase": {
                                "ACCOUNT.keyword": "searchValue"
                              }
                            }
                          ],
                          "minimum_should_match": 1
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "bool": {
                          "should": [
                            {
                              "match_phrase": {
                                "APPLICATION_NAME.keyword": "searchValue"
                              }
                            }
                          ],
                          "minimum_should_match": 1
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "range": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                      "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
                      "gte": "2022-03-21T09:09:09.277Z",
                      "lte": "2022-03-25T09:09:09.277Z"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you want to see all the fields in your index named `XXX`, after applying the filter values `monitoring` and `webApp`.

You don't have to do anything as Elasticsearch by default, returns the `_source` (which contains all the values ie fields in your document JSON).

Example:

**Index sample docs**

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "title": "bar",
    "account" : "monitoring",
    "app" : "webapp"
}
{
    "name": "abc",
    "title": "def",
    "account" : "observe",
    "app" : "webapp"
}
```

And search query according to your requirement(some filters).

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "account": "monitoring"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "app": "webapp"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And search result

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "71614025",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.0,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "foo",
                    "title": "bar",
                    "account": "monitoring",
                    "app": "webapp"
                }
            }
        ]
```

**Notice all the indexed fields in your search result, under the hits section in the search response.**

Comment: No :) unfortunately, you didn't get the question, I don't want to select the whole record, I only want one field to be extracted from the record that this filter matches it.

the result should be a list of values of the filename field.